# Java 7u25 allowAmbigousCommands property not working

Tags: java-7

Java system property allowAmbigousCommands is not working for me on Windows 7, 7u25 32b  JRE:

```
System.setProperty("jdk.lang.Process.allowAmbigousCommands", "true");
try {
    Process p= Runtime.getRuntime().exec("foo.bat > myOutput.txt");
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

where the content of foo.bat is:

echo "hello world"

I've also checked using *-Djdk.lang.Process.allowAmbigousCommands=true* with no success.
Any clue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happen when you try it?

Comment: The file  myOutput.txt is not created, no exception or error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*jdk.lang.Process.allowAmbigousCommands* won't help with *batch* file executions.

Run `exec()` as

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /C \"foo.bat > myOutput.txt\"");
```

***Reference** :*
[JDK 7u25: Solutions to Issues caused by changes to Runtime.exec()](https://blogs.oracle.com/java/post/jdk-7u25-solutions-to-issues-caused-by-changes-to-runtimeexec)

Comment: Then, in case I have Runtime.getRuntime().exec("foo.bat > myOutput.txt"); there is no workaround using system properties, right?

Comment: No, there's not. The system property workaround only works for ambiguous paths containing spaces in file or directory names.

Comment: Right Ravi, thank you. Suppose I can't modify my code, -Djdk.lang.Process.allowAmbigousCommands won't help to run my old code so from now on my application would be broken, it sounds strange not to have alternatives.

Comment: Sorry, mate. Your case has been covered explicitly in Problem 2: "Shell command/.bat/.cmd IO redirection". All the solutions proposed require a code change. Ideally, the application shouldn't have hard-coded the value. That's why externalising strings to a .properties file is so recommended. It would have saved you the trouble.

Comment: I appreciate your clarification. Thanks!